# How to implement conditional validating in form for option selected?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, conditional-statements

Here is the section of App.js that I'm concerned with:

```
errorMessage=(validator, input, value, e)=> {
  const valid=validator(value)
  if (value==="") {
    input.nextElementSibling.style.display="inherit"
    e.preventDefault()
  } else if (!valid && value!=="") {
    input.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling.style.display="inherit"
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}

const checkedCheckboxes=Array.from(checkboxes).filter(checkbox=> checkbox.checked);

validateCheckboxes=(e)=> {
  const checked=checkedCheckboxes.length;
  if (!checked) {
    fieldSetActivity.nextElementSibling.style.display="block"
    e.preventDefault()
  }
}

creditOptionChecked=()=> {
  Array.from(paymentOptions).forEach(option=> {
    if (option.selected) {
      if (option.value==="Credit Card") {
        return true
      }
    }
  })
}


validateForm=(e)=> {
  Array.from(inputElements).forEach(element=> {
    let value=element.value;
    let input=element;
    if (input===name) {
      errorMessage(isValidName, input, value, e)
    } else if (element===email) {
      errorMessage(isValidEmail, input, value, e);
    } else if (element===creditNumber) {
      errorMessage(isValidCreditCard, input, value, e);
    } else if (element===zip) {
      errorMessage(isValidZipCode, input, value, e);
    } else if (element===cvv) {
      errorMessage(isValidCvv, input, value, e);
    } else if (element==fieldSetActivity) {
      validateCheckboxes(e)
    }
  });
}



form.addEventListener('submit', (e)=> {
  validateForm(e)
  console.log("hello")
})
```

I only want the form to the credit card number input, zip, and cvv when the credit card option is choosen. I created a function to check for this, called **creditOptionChecked**, however I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implemenent this in my **validateForm** function in a modular way.

I still want the array to be iterating over the elements and caling a function as such as ErrorMessage on each one, but how could I introduce a conditional to check for creditOptionChecked, without implementing this in a seperate function. Is it possible to do this all within the **validateForm** function?

Thanks

**EDIT

No I only want the form to validate the **credit card fields** (number, zip, cvv) when the credit card option in the **I'm going to pay with** menu is selected.

Comment: Are you using React ? This would be really simple to do in react.

Comment: Ah okay, sorry it kinda looked like react. I guess I'm a little confused because the credit card text fields only show when the Credit Card is selected already (and it is selected by default).. Do you want it to not be the default option?